# Cannot find USB virtual comport with QtSerialPort on BeagleBone Black

Tags: c++, qt, usb, beagleboneblack, qtserialport

I'm starting a new embedded software project with Qt Enterprise (Boot2Qt evaluation version so far), and try to use QtSerialPort to detect all virtual comports in my system. Actually I just simply tried the cenumerator example in serialport example folder in Qt 5.2.1. It runs perfectly in both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04 desktop, but when I run it on BeagleBone Black with Boot2Qt, the virtual comport cannot be found by using QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts(). It only list 5 comports: ttyO0, ttyS0, ttyS1, ttyS2, ttyS3, which I believe are the default comports on BeagleBone Black. The USB virtual comport which should be listed as ttyUSB0 is missing.

I also tried to login to the Angstrom system on BeagleBone Black, and it seems like "/dev/ttyUSB0" does exist.

Does anybody have any idea of what did I do wrong or did I miss something?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: QtSerialPort is not supported or Boot2Qt. Also, what do you mean by virtual comport, a regular usb-serial dongle? Moreover, you have not mentioned the operating system running on your BeagleBone Black either.

Comment: The enumerator is probably simply ignoring the `ttyUSB` entries in the `dev` folder. You'll need to debug the enumerator and see what it does.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and I'm not sure QtSerialPort is not supported by Boot2Qt, since it does recognized 5 default com ports on Beaglebone black. And they even works fine if I connect them to a PC. Yes, I mean a usb-serial dongle (using FTDI chip inside). The operating system I'm running with Beaglebone black is Angstrom, the default image came with it. I'll try to debug it.

Comment: I have never seen any /dev/ttyUSB0 virtual comport. Can you provide more information?

Answer (score 0):

you can find the port in /dev/ttyACM0